# How to get search for a listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi Everyone i am new to android and having some trouble in one particular case. The scenario is we should have a search included to list view which i generated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

ListView has a pretty useful feature - maybe it fits your needs:
[setTextFilterEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29)

`getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);`